# Can't read more than 1 level in on JSON

Tags: node.js, json

So I made this JSON File...

```
{ 'Blue Aces Bakery':
{ Symbol: 'BAB',
 Stock:
  { onSale: {},
    Shares: 13,
    Price: 10,
    marketCap: 130,
    Balance: 10075,
    stockOpen: 10,
    previousClose: 10,
    chartFile: './public/BAB',
    Intraday: [Array],
    previousIntraday: [Array] 
    } 
    } 
}
```

But when I run this code

```
var stockData = require('./stocks.json');
console.log(stockData[Companies])
if(stockData[Companies].Stock.onSale.Bids) {...
```

I get this:

```
{ 'Blue Aces Bakery':
{ Symbol: 'BAB',
 Stock:
  { onSale: {},
    Shares: 13,
    Price: 10,
    marketCap: 130,
    Balance: 10075,
    stockOpen: 10,
    previousClose: 10,
    chartFile: './public/BAB',
    Intraday: [Array],
    previousIntraday: [Array] } } }

  (node:14680) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'onSale' of undefined
at checkStocks (C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Stock Bot\base.js:30:39)
```

This makes zero sense to me. Can someone assist me with what I'm doing wrong here? I already tried looking it up, and no one else appears to have the same problem.

Comment: If you're logging `stockData[Companies]` and getting the contents of the entire JSON file, you likely have other problems... In other words, if `stockData[Companies]` has a single property named `'Blue Aces Bakery'`, then a property named `Stock` doesn't exist on `stockData[Companies]`...

Answer (score 0):

`console.log()` only shows a few levels of deep objects.

You will want to use `console.dir()` (which depends on version etc.) or [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options).

Demo:

```
$ node 
> let a = {}; a.b = {}; a.b.c = {}; a.b.c.d = {}; a.b.c.d.e = [0,1,2,3,4];
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
> console.log(a)
{ b: { c: { d: [Object] } } }
undefined
> console.dir(a)
{ b: { c: { d: [Object] } } }
undefined
> console.log(util.inspect(a, false, null, true))
{ b: { c: { d: { e: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ] } } } }
undefined
> process.version
'v10.14.1'
>
```